# Magento 2 custom module shortened url with query string goes 404

Tags: module, controllers, magento2.2.2, querystring

I have a custom controller page :

```
http://dev.test/myfrontend/
```

The above works fine. also the bellow one works

```
http://dev.test/myfrontend/index/index/
```

Now if I add query string:

```
http://dev.test/myfrontend/index/index/viewid/2
```

this loads the page fine and I can get parameters fine

But if I load like the this:

`http://dev.test/myfrontend/viewid/2   // It fail Miserably goes 404`

This should work without adding /index/index !

Does anyone have nay idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Go to marketing > url rewrite > add url rewrite
- under request path adding myfrontend/viewid
- under target path add myfrontend/index/index/viewid

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I looking for I should mention the the viewid   is dinamic so it can any anything like ../banana/3